# Convert numbers to time, or in other words, insert : in the middle of a string

Tags: php, string, time

how would I be able to inser a : in the middle of numbers like 840 or 1530. I basically want to add a : at the third last position, as I got some strings with 3 and some with 4 numbers in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$x = '1930';
echo substr($x, 0, strlen($x) - 2) . ':' . substr($x, strlen($x) - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
<?php
$int = 1530;
$str = (string) $int;
$newstring = substr_replace($str, ':', 3, 0);
echo $newstring;
?>
```